# Static lifetime causes "borrowed value does not live long enough" when it really does

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

There are about 50 questions on Stack Overflow about "borrowed value does not live long enough", but I haven't found one that answers this question. Here's the code:

```
struct ArrayStruct {
    pub buf: [u8; 10],
}

struct StaticRefStruct {
    pub buf: &'static [u8],
}

fn test() {
    let mut array_struct = ArrayStruct { buf: [0u8; 10] };
    let array_slice = &mut array_struct.buf[..];
    let static_ref = StaticRefStruct { buf: array_slice };
}
```

and the error:

```
11 |     let array_slice = &mut array_struct.buf[..];
   |                       -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----
   |                       |    |
   |                       |    borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                       assignment requires that `array_struct.buf` is borrowed for `'static`
12 |     let static_ref = StaticRefStruct { buf: array_slice };
13 | }
   | - `array_struct.buf` dropped here while still borrowed
```

No, `array_struct.buf` is not still borrowed when it is dropped. `static_ref`, which borrows it, gets dropped at the same time. Adding an explicit `drop(static_ref);` before the end of the function doesn't solve the problem.

The difficulty is the 'static lifetime in `StaticRefStruct`, but that is the correct lifetime for my app. `buf` in this case is coming from an external C function, and it really does live until I explicitly tell the C func that we no longer need it. Giving it a different lifetime forces me to pollute the code with a ton of `<'a>` all the way up a very long call tree.

How do I get the compiler to not object to this code?

Comment: *"[The] 'static lifetime ... is the correct lifetime for my app ... it really does live until I explicitly tell the C func that we no longer need it"* - that's not what `'static` means. The `'static` lifetime means it can be referenced until the end of the program, not until you say so.

Comment: @kmdreko What other lifetime label would I use to tell Rust that I will manage the lifetime of this reference myself, so don't worry about it?

Comment: In Rust, those are called pointers.

Comment: Can you describe your C FFI in more detail? Including what functions do what and how they affect the lifetime of objects?

Comment: @kmdreko A bit tough to do in just a comment, but this is a Postgres extension that needs zero-copy pointers to internal Postgres buffers. I lock and unlock buffers explicitly. Something like `read_buf(...)->std::os::raw::c_char`. I then use `slice::from_raw_parts()` to make a &[u8].

Comment: You can edit your post with more details. Generally it is possible to make a safe layer between the FFI layer and the rest of your Rust code and able to use references. It usually means creating a wrapper around the pointer/handle/identifier (say `struct BufHandle(c_char)`) from which you can create references tied to that wrapper object. Then, the function that "destroys" the buffer would consume the wrapper object, meaning the Rust compiler will not allow you to keep any references derived from it afterwards. If you provide the specifics, I can write up a more direct answer.

Comment: @kmdreko This is a good idea. I could just store the raw pointer in the struct and convert it as necessary, maybe. Let me work on it and I'll post again later.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
struct RefStruct<'a> {
    buf: &'a [u8],
}

type StaticRefStruct = RefStruct<'static>;
```

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't solve it if I use StaticRefStruct in this example, but using RefStruct directly gets rid of the error. I'll need to explore whether my app can use one type in some places and the different type elsewhere.